# how can i run jersey 2.26 with JDK 1.7?

Tags: java, jersey, java-7, jersey-2.0

I'm using JDK1.7 for my application.

I upgrade jersey 2.26 and now I am getting the error :

```
严重: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/spcsis-1.0] threw load() exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3129)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I've change the jdk to 1.8 and then it works, but i have to use jdk1.7 for my project .

somebody can help me to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Jersey 2.26, all modules support only Java SE 8

See jersey [dependencies](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html):

> Until version 2.6, Jersey was compiled with Java SE 6. This has
>   changed in Jersey 2.7.
>
> Up to version 2.25.x almost all Jersey components are compiled with
>   Java SE 7 target. It means, that you will need at least Java SE 7 to
>   be able to compile and run your application that is using latest
>   Jersey. Only core-common and core-client modules are still compiled
>   with Java class version runnable with Java SE 6.
>
> Since Jersey 2.26, all modules are build using Java SE 8 and there is
>   no support for running it on older Java SE distributions.

Comment: so  i had better to change jersey 2.26 to 2.25,  then i can use JDK 1.7. right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your only option would be to rebuild jersey using Java 7.

Comment: may be  i can use jersey 2.25 ,  which version is build with java 7?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Jersey up to the 2.13, this is the last version which has been compiled by the JDK 1.7 (please look at the MANIFEST inside the JAR).